# Identifier 'title' is not defined. '{}' does not contain such a member angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

**This is my component file:**

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CategoriesService } from 'src/app/categories.service';
import { ProductService } from 'src/app/product.service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-forms',
  templateUrl: './product-forms.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-forms.component.css']
})
export class ProductFormsComponent implements OnInit {

categories$;
product: {};

  constructor(categoryservice: CategoriesService , private productservice: ProductService , private router: Router,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.categories$ = categoryservice.getcategories();

    let id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    if (id) { this.productservice.get(id).take(1).subscribe(p => this.product = p); }
   }

   save(product) {
     this.productservice.create(product);
     this.router.navigate(['/admin/products']);
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**This is my html file**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title >Title</title>
</head>

</html>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">

    <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(f.value)">

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input #title="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="product.title" name="title" id="title" type="text" class="form-control" required>
        ***<!-- ERROR  : Identifier 'title' is not defined. '{}' does not contain such a member -->***
        <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="title.touched && title.invalid">
          Title is required
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="price">Price</label>
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text">$</span>
        <input #price="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="product.price" name="price" id="price" type="number" class="form-control" required [min]="0">
      <!--ERROR  :  Identifier 'price' is not defined. '{}' does not contain such a member -->
      </div>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="price.touched && price.invalid">
          <div *ngIf="price.errors.required">Price is required</div>
          <div *ngIf="price.errors.min">Price must be 0 or higher than zero</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="category">Cateogary</label>
        <select #category="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="product.category" name="category" id="category"  class="form-control" required>
<!--ERROR  :  Identifier 'category' is not defined. '{}' does not contain such a member -->
          <option value=""></option>
          <option *ngFor="let c of categories$ | async" [value]="c.$key">

            {{ c.name }}

          </option>
        </select>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="category.touched && category.invalid">
          Category is required
      </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="imageurl">Image Url</label>
        <input #imageUrl="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="product.imageurl" name="imageUrl" id="imageurl" type="text" class="form-control" required url>
        <!--ERROR  :  Identifier 'imageurl' is not defined. '{}' does not contain such a member -->
        <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="imageUrl.touched && imageUrl.invalid">
          <div *ngIf="imageUrl.errors.required">ImageUrl is required</div>
          <div *ngIf="imageUrl.errors.url">ImageUrl is required</div>

      </div>
      </div>

      <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>

      </form>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img [src]="product.imageUrl" class="card-img-top" alt="..." *ngIf="product.imageUrl">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title"> {{product.title}} </h5>
         <!-- ERROR  : Identifier 'title' is not defined. '{}' does not contain such a member -->
        <p class="card-text"> {{product.price | currency:'USD':true}} </p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

- **Whenever i deploy my project i get these following errors:**

  - Identifier 'imageurl' is not defined. '{}' does not contain such a member
  - Identifier 'title' is not defined. '{}' does not contain such a member
  - Identifier 'category' is not defined. '{}' does not contain such a member
  - Identifier 'price' is not defined.'{}' does not contain such a member
  - Identifier 'title' is not defined. '{}' does not contain such a member

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try defining a class or interface with the fields needed for product ( `imageurl`, etc), then import this to your component and create the product variable as the new type e.g. `product: Product;` instead of `product: {};`

E.g.
new file product.ts

```
export class Product
{
    imageUrl: string;
    title: string;
    //etc
}
```

existing component.ts:

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CategoriesService } from 'src/app/categories.service';
import { ProductService } from 'src/app/product.service';
import { Product } from 'src/app/product';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-forms',
  templateUrl: './product-forms.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-forms.component.css']
})
export class ProductFormsComponent implements OnInit {

categories$;
product: Product;

  constructor(categoryservice: CategoriesService , private productservice: ProductService , private router: Router,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.categories$ = categoryservice.getcategories();

    let id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    if (id) { this.productservice.get(id).take(1).subscribe(p => this.product = p); }
   }

   save(product) {
     this.productservice.create(product);
     this.router.navigate(['/admin/products']);
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Where you make the http call to retrieve the product data, also import and specify the Product type e.g:

```
get(): Observable<Product> {
  return this.http.get<Product>(exampleUrl);
}
```

Comment: I have tried this. But Now I get a new error.                                                                        In following line. if (id) { this.productservice.get(id).take(1).subscribe(p => this.product = p); } .Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '{ title: string; price: number; imageurl: string; }'

Comment: Can you show your code changes? It looks like it is not recognising the Product type. Also in your http call are you specifying a type for the returned data to map to e.g: return this.http.get<Product>

Comment: I have changed above code to this: " product: Product ". And created an interface with 'Product' name. Where I've defined the type of "title","price" etc

Comment: I've edited my answer to show changes to your component and example of http call.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined `product` as being a type with no properties: `product: {};` This is what the error means - you haven't said that `product` has a `title`, `price`, etc. If you add the properties it should then work.

```
product: {
   title: string;
   price: number;
   //etc.
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need create interface object Product

```
export interface Product {
   title: string,
}
```

Comment: ...and also declare `product`variable with this interface `product: Product;`

Comment: Now I get a new error: Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'Product'. In the following line.................."        if (id) { this.productservice.get(id).take(1).subscribe(p => this.product = p); }               "

Comment: in what form do you get the data from subscribe. Please show me result console.log(p, 'Product');.